# Access Webforms in different projects under one solution in Asp .net.Visual studio 2012

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two Different projects TestOne and TestTwo.I have added them under one solution.Now my problem is that I want to access webform1.aspx located in TestOne from Webform1.aspx page located in TestTwo when a Hyperlink is clicked in the webform1.aspx page in Test2.

Answer (score 0):

When the projects are have been built and are being debuged, you will notice two development web server instances. There is one for each of your web projects.

Simply create links that use the other web applications address.  However, be aware that as you are in development the port numbers are automatically assigned and may change.